# How to install Brotli CLI on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: yum, aws

The ubuntu manpage lists the [brotli cli](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/brotli.1.html) which can be [installed](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/brotli) like this:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y brotli
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add this package to the Amazon Linux AMI which uses `yum install` from this [package repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#package-repository)

```bsh
$ yum search "brotli"
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
1072 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Warning: No matches found for: brotli
No matches found
```

Here's the official [google repo for brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli), but I can't figure out how to expose it as a CLI after running `pip install brotli`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading the repository and using cmake to install it on Amazon Linux.

```
 yum -y groupinstall "development tools"  # this installs a lot, you may not need.
 yum install cmake 
 git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/google/brotli.git
 mkdir out && cd out
 cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./installed ..
 cmake --build . --config Release --target install
```

This created a single binary (program) I could use in `/path/to/repo/out/installed/bin/brotli` So I moved it into my path  `mv /path/to/repo/out/installed/bin/brotli /usr/bin` and then I was good to go. You can remove the cloned repo after that as well.

I have not used the Pip version but you can probably do `python3 -m brotli ...`. Just guessing though.